# Publish GitHub repo subfolder to GitHub pages, keeping subfolder path

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a repository called, let's say, `odds-and-ends`. Within that repo is the folder, `js-projects`, and then another folder within that is `quick-js-app`. `quick-js-app` contains all the ingredients of a basic web page, including an `index.html`, CSS and JS file, etc.

It's quite easy to publish the subdirectory `quick-js-app` to GitHub pages (for example, [this gist by cobyism](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) tells how to do so).

But, is it possible to publish `quick-js-app` so that it retains the file path, i.e., it would be located at `http://myusername.github.io/odds-and-ends/js-projects/quick-js-app`?

(Note, someone asks about this [here](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490#gistcomment-1859681) within the gist thread from above - Gulp is suggested as a solution, but I didn't have any luck with it.)

Does anyone have a suggestion for me?

Comment: No one has a suggestion? :( Perhaps it's simply not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If branch `gh-pages` already exists, delete it.

```
git branch -D gh-pages
```

Create a new branch `gh-pages` without any content.

```
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
```

Remove all initially cached files from the index.

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Add, commit, and push `js-projects/quick-js-app`.  If `gh-pages` is already on github, you need to force the push using `-f`.  Be aware that this deletes all already existing content in different directories like `js-projects/complex-js-app`.

```
git add js-projects/quick-js-app
git commit -m "Publish"
git push [-f] origin gh-pages
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I really appreciate it!  
It works really well and I am going to experiment with publishing several subdirectories too.